# S3 storage of static files using staticfiles app in Django 1.2.5 possible?

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, django-staticfiles

I have a website running on Django 1.2.5 which doesn't include the staticfiles app. I have however installed the staticfiles app via pip:

```
sudo pip install django-staticfiles
```

I then added the staticfiles app to settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS += (
    'staticfiles',
```

however when I restart the server a get a 502 Bad Gateway error and the following error in /var/log/uwsgi/app/my-site.log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/var/projects/my-site/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 248, in __call__
  response = self.get_response(request)
 File "/var/projects/my-site/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 141, in get_response
  return self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
 File "/var/projects/my-site/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 165, in handle_uncaught_exception
  return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
 File "/var/projects/my-site/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 59, in technical_500_response
html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
 File "/var/projects/my-site/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 141, in get_traceback_html
  return t.render(c)
 File "/var/projects/my-site/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/__init__.py", line 173, in render
  return self._render(context)
 File "/var/projects/my-site/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/__init__.py", line 167, in _render
  return self.nodelist.render(context)
 File "/var/projects/my-site/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/__init__.py", line 796, in render
bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
 File "/var/projects/my-site/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/__init__.py", line 809, in render_node
  return node.render(context)
 File "/var/projects/my-site/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/__init__.py", line 844, in render
output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
 File "/var/projects/my-site/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/__init__.py", line 579, in resolve
new_obj = func(obj, *arg_vals)
 File "/var/projects/my-site/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaultfilters.py", line 682, in date
  return format(value, arg)
 File "/var/projects/my-site/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 281, in format
  return df.format(format_string)
 File "/var/projects/my-site/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 30, in format
pieces.append(force_unicode(getattr(self, piece)()))
 File "/var/projects/my-site/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 187, in r
  return self.format('D, j M Y H:i:s O')
 File "/var/projects/my-site/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 30, in format
pieces.append(force_unicode(getattr(self, piece)()))
 File "/var/projects/my-site/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 66, in force_unicode
s = unicode(s)
 File "/var/projects/my-site/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 206, in __unicode_cast
  return self.__func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)
 File "/var/projects/my-site/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 55, in ugettext
  return real_ugettext(message)
 File "/var/projects/my-site/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 55, in _curried
  return _curried_func(*(args+moreargs), **dict(kwargs, **morekwargs))
 File "/var/projects/my-site/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 36, in delayed_loader
  return getattr(trans, real_name)(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/var/projects/my-site/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 276, in ugettext
  return do_translate(message, 'ugettext')
 File "/var/projects/my-site/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 266, in do_translate
_default = translation(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
 File "/var/projects/my-site/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 176, in translation
default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
 File "/var/projects/my-site/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 159, in _fetch
app = import_module(appname)
 File "/var/projects/my-site/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named staticfiles
```

However I can import staticfiles when I run the following command from my Virtualenv folder:

```
$ python manage.py shell
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> import staticfiles
>>>
```

Essentially, I am trying to move the static files to S3 according to this blog post:

https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/11/10/Using-Amazon-S3-to-store-your-Django-sites-static-and-media-files/

Is it possible to use the staticfiles app in Django 1.2.5 or do I have to upgrade Django?

I would rather not upgrade Django because I am sure this will break many other parts of the site.

What other options are there? I assume it would possible to use boto somehow instead?

Comment: My mistake: I had not activated my virtualenv when I ran the import staticfiles command. I did source `/var/projects/my-site/env/bin/activate` then `python manage.py shell` then `python manage.py shell
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> import staticfiles
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named staticfiles`. So I assume this method of storing files on S3 is not possible with Django <1.3 ?

Comment: It sounds like you haven't installed `staticfiles` inside the virtualenv. Do `source /var/projects/my-site/env/bin/activate` then `pip install django-staticfiles` (sudo shouldn't be required).

Comment: Please upgrade Django. 1.2.5 is extremely out of date, there have been many security fixes since then.

Answer (score 0):

`django-storage` is not compatible with Django 1.2.2, unfortunately.
According to https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages

> This library is usually compatible with the currently supported versions of Django. Check the trove classifiers in setup.py to be sure.